# Q: Sourcetree error : 'git status' failed with code -1"

Tags: ssh, atlassian-sourcetree, apple-m1, status

Sourcetree showing this error  `'git status' failed with code -1"` while trying access project from bookmark, also I can't clone any other project from remote list or manual by url.

SSH connection is good. Command
`ssh -T git@github.com` showing - `Hi "name"! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.`
Command `git clone` also works fine and fetch project.

Answer (score 27):

Resolved by clicking `options > git > Use System Git` and set to use System Git Version.

Comment: On macOS `Preferences > Git > Use System Git`

Comment: On newer macOS Sourcetree upper left corner -> Settings (⌘ ,) -> Git version -> Use system git